# URL re-write syntax

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a URL:
"http://www.lootza.com/Model/Public/BuyNow/buynow.php?str=NDA="

I want to re-write this url as below:

"http://www.lootza.com/buynow/NDA="

I tried to do this by writing this below code in .htaccess but not getting any luck.

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /Model/Public/Home/
RewriteRule ^buynow/([0-9]+)/?$ Model/Public/BuyNow/buynow.php?str=$1

Please give me write syntax.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

That seems correct assuming `NDA=` is an numeric string.

You can use the following to speed up your future test cycles:
http://civilolydnad.se/projects/rewriterule/